# BOINC can't connect to local host

Tags: localhost, 19.04, boinc

Have just upgraded online from 18.10 to 19.04 (desktop 64 bit).
BOINC has worked previously but now won't run. BOINC Manager is greyed out and shows 'connecting to localhost'. Trying 'boinccmd' always returns 'can't connect to local host'.
It has been suggested that it's a firewall problem, but gufw doesn't have a profile for BOINC.
Since this is only since upgrade could this be a Ubuntu 19.04 problem?

Comment: Maybe something new: I see now that OpenCL packages are installed, yet running 'clinfo' just hangs, suggesting a problem with OpenCL. Since BOINC uses this, are we seeing another part of the same problem?